# PHP rename folder in directory

Tags: php, explode, file-rename

How can i get `$filename` to be one specific path? Not a specific folder?
I want to rename several folders in folder named `output`.

I tried this:

```
$fileName = '/path/folder/output';
```

Here is my original code:

```
<?php

        $fileName = '351437-367628';
        $newNametemp = explode("-",$fileName);
        if(is_array($newNametemp)){
            $newName = $newNametemp[0];
            print_r($newName); // lar navnet stå att etter første bindestrek
            rename($fileName, $newName);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of your script and turn `display_errors` on in your server config for **development**. So you will likely see an error caused by `rename()`.

Comment: the renaming works , but i dont know how to choose all folders in this output folder

Comment: `readdir()` or `scandir()` for example will read all the content in the directory. There are also SPL Iterators for Directories and RecursiveDirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file_path = "uploads/";
$input = $_POST['name_of _the_folder_You WIsh']; // this is the new folder you'll create
$file_path .= $input . '/';
if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
mkdir($file_path);
}
chmod($file_path, 0777);

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script that does (I think) what you're looking for.  It loops through a directory, renaming all subdirectories.
Save code to *demo.php*, and *chmod +x demo.php* && *./demo.php*.

If you'd prefer an object-oriented approach, or need any changes let me know and I'll modify the code.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php


//root directory
$outputDir = '/path/folder/output';

//get all subdirectories in the root directory
$dirs = scandir($outputDir);
if ($dirs === FALSE) {
  echo "scandir() failed.\n";
  exit(1);
}

//loop through each subdirectory and rename.
foreach($dirs as $dir) {
  $newName = "${dir}.tmp";  //rename as needed; here we append ".tmp" to the subdirectory.
  $success = rename($dir, $newName);
  if (!$success) 
    echo "Rename of $dir failed.\n";  //there was an error during rename, handle it.
}
```